# Keyboard occasionally stops working, mouse works

Tags: 14.04, keyboard, lubuntu, dell

I have a user whose keyboard occasionally stops working until the system is rebooted. This is completely random and happens 0 to ~7 times a day. There hasn't been any problems with the mouse, only keyboard.

System details: Dell Vostro 270S (desktop) with a Dell keyboard, Lubuntu 14.04.1 x86 3.13.0-44-generic.

Things I have tried:

- Another keyboard (HP basic keyboard, as seen in dmesg)
- Another USB port
- apt upgrade

I would try PS/2 instead of USB, but there's no such port in the computer.

Here's the dmesg output (there's no disconnecting or other problems further in the log):

```
[    1.667034] usb 3-3: new low-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[    1.691751] usb 3-3: New USB device found, idVendor=03f0, idProduct=0324
[    1.691754] usb 3-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    1.691756] usb 3-3: Product: HP Basic USB Keyboard
[    1.691757] usb 3-3: Manufacturer: Lite-On Technology Corp.
[    1.691882] usb 3-3: ep 0x81 - rounding interval to 64 microframes, ep desc says 80 microframes
[    1.697618] hidraw: raw HID events driver (C) Jiri Kosina
[    1.704187] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[    1.704189] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[    1.707134] input: Lite-On Technology Corp. HP Basic USB Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-3/3-3:1.0/input/input5
[    1.707196] hid-generic 0003:03F0:0324.0001: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [Lite-On Technology Corp. HP Basic USB Keyboard] on usb-0000:00:14.0-3/input0
[    1.771260] usb 2-1.5: new low-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
[    1.868124] usb 2-1.5: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=c077
[    1.868129] usb 2-1.5: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    1.868132] usb 2-1.5: Product: USB Optical Mouse
[    1.868135] usb 2-1.5: Manufacturer: Logitech
[    1.870258] input: Logitech USB Optical Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.5/2-1.5:1.0/input/input6
[    1.870329] hid-generic 0003:046D:C077.0002: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [Logitech USB Optical Mouse] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.5/input0
```

lsusb:

```
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 046d:c077 Logitech, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 03f0:0324 Hewlett-Packard SK-2885 keyboard
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

syslog when the keyboard stops working and system is rebooted:

```
Jan 19 09:48:14 machine-04 NetworkManager[768]: <info> (eth0): IP6 addrconf timed out or failed.
Jan 19 09:48:14 machine-04 NetworkManager[768]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) scheduled...
Jan 19 09:48:14 machine-04 NetworkManager[768]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) started...
Jan 19 09:48:14 machine-04 NetworkManager[768]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) complete.
Jan 19 09:48:24 machine-04 ntpd_intres[764]: parent died before we finished, exiting
Jan 19 09:57:23 machine-04 dbus[668]: [system] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.systemd1' (using servicehelper)
Jan 19 09:57:23 machine-04 dbus[668]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1'
Jan 19 09:57:23 machine-04 rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="7.4.4" x-pid="663" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] exiting on signal 15.
Jan 19 09:57:49 machine-04 rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="7.4.4" x-pid="675" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] start
Jan 19 09:57:49 machine-04 rsyslogd: rsyslogd's groupid changed to 104
Jan 19 09:57:49 machine-04 rsyslogd: rsyslogd's userid changed to 101
```

I'm out of ideas. Any leads?

Answer (score 0):

I'd assume it was a hardware / keyboard problem, but if it happens on 2 different keyboards... Could try a 3rd keyboard I suppose, just in case of the unlikely 2 bad keyboards.

Any updates or changes just before this started happening? Software / kernel updates? rolling back to a previous working version, or a newer version could hlep...
Trying a live dvd/usb of a different version (older or newer) could provide more info, if it never happens with a newer kernel/version then updating should help.

And next time unplug & re-plug the USB keyboard, see if it resets & starts working again, or provides some interesting error messages about why it won't.

Answer (score 0):

I have that problem.  It is both the physical keyboard associated with the computer, and during those same times, the Onboard virtual keyboard also doesn't input.  It's so weird.